# Palindrome Checker in C

Tags: c, string

Where should I include toupper() in my code in order to make a palindrome such as Noon or NoOoON to say it is a palindrome rather than saying it is not a palindrome. I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

void reverse(char s[]){ 
    int c, i , j; 
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i < j; i++, j--) { 
        c = s[i]; 
        s[i] = s[j]; 
        s[j] = c; 
    } 
    return; 
} 

int main(){ 
    char a[20];
    char b[20];
    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    gets(a);
    strcpy(b,a); // copies string a to b 
    reverse(a); // reverses string b
    if(strcmp(a, b) == 0) { // compares if the original and reverse strings are the same 
        printf("The string is a Palindrome\n"); 
    } 
    else { 
        printf("The string is not a Palindrome\n"); 
    }    
    return 0; 
}
```

---

Comment: Don't use `gets` use `fgets`

Comment: do not use toupper(), converts character to Upper case . You need to change entire Input string character by character and then reverse and compare.just use case insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can just use `_stricmp` instead of `strcmp`.

Another way to approach this is to convert your string to a single case after it is input. *eg*

```
for (char *c = a; *c; c++) *c = toupper(*c);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `toupper()` then you should apply it before you make a copy of the string and reverse it.

That is:

```
int main() { 
    char a[20];
    char b[20];
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    gets(a);
    // make the change here
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
        a[i] = toupper(a[i]);
    }
    strcpy(b, a);
```

If you convert the string to a single case later, then the copy will not be the same as the original, or you'd have to `toupper()` both.

Comment: Do you know what the `toupper` function does?

Comment: toupper takes as a parameter a character, not an array

Comment: My bad, hasty copy-paste. Not used C in a while :) But at least I am trying to answer the question that was asked - I'll fix that now.

Comment: @Smac89 toupper takes an `int`, not a character. And the arg should be cast to an int. This becomes important if the string contains characters with the eigth bit set and plain char is signed.